# Testing Mailgun .send() method with Mocha and Sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, mailgun

I am trying to write unit tests for an express middleware function that sends an email by pinging the Mailgun API.

```
module.exports = {
  sendEmail: function (req, res) {
    let reqBody = req.body;
    let to = reqBody.to;
    let from = reqBody.from;
    let subject = reqBody.subject;
    let emailBody = reqBody.body;

    let data = {
      from: from,
      to: to,
      subject: subject,
      text: emailBody
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json(error);
        return;
      }
      res.status(200).json(body);
    });
  }
};
```

The test file:

```
  describe('\'sendEmail\' method', () => {
    let mailgun;
    beforeEach(() => {
      mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: MAIL_GUN_API_KEY, domain: MAIL_GUN_DOMAIN });
    });

    it.only('should send the data to the MailGun API', (done) => {    
      sinon.spy(mailgun, 'messages');
      sinon.spy(mailgun.messages(), 'send');

      emailMiddleware.sendEmail(request, response);
      // using sinon-chai here
      mailgun.messages().send.should.have.been.called();
      done();    
    });
```

Result upon running `npm test`:

```
TypeError: [Function] is not a spy or a call to a spy!
```

> 1. How can I test if the `.send` method is being called in `mailgun.messages().send(...)`?
> 2. I am directly using the mailgun API. How can I stub out mailgun itself?

Answer (score 5):

You have to stub `mailgun-js` you have to stub this package and after you could check the returns you want

Because you are using callback, don't forget to return it

```
const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
sandbox.stub(mailgun({ apiKey: 'foo', domain: 'bar' }).Mailgun.prototype, 'messages')
  .returns({
    send: (data, cb) => cb(),
  });

// Your stuff...

sandbox.restore();
```

You can use the `sandbox.spy()` to check what you want, the behavior is the same as `sinon.spy()` [Doc here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/sandbox/#sandboxspy)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I test if the .send method is being called in
>   mailgun.messages().send(...)?

You need to stub the method `send`, not just spy on it and make it act like the real method.

This is what I do when I want to stub the mailgun-js module.

```
    // Mock sandbox
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()

    mailgunSendSpy = sandbox.stub().yields(null, { bo: 'dy' })
    sandbox.stub(Mailgun({ apiKey: 'foo', domain: 'bar' }).Mailgun.prototype, 'messages').returns({
      send: mailgunSendSpy
    })
```

The `yields` methods pass the arguments `null` and `{bo: 'dy'}` to the first callback it founds.

I think it answers your other question too.

Answer (score 1):

```
const stubs = {};
//Make a stub for the send method.
stubs.mailgunSendStub = sinon.stub(
  { send: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(null)) },
  'send'
);
stubs.mailgunMessagesStub = sinon
  .stub(mailgun({ apiKey: 'k', domain: 'd' }).Mailgun.prototype, 'messages')
  .returns({
    send: stubs.mailgunSendStub, //call it here.
  });

 //Now you can test the call counts and also the arguments passed to the send() method.
 expect(stubs.mailgunSendStub.callCount).toBe(1);
 expect(stubs.mailgunSendStub.args[0][0]).toStrictEqual(someData);
```